# Total entries in .pbf

Tags: qgis, pbf

I'm trying to convert osm.pbf to .shp for some analysis in QGIS. I need to verify id the converted .shp is the same as .pbf. 
But the attributes table shows only 99 records by default. How do i find the total number of entries?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the layer in the layers panel, and choose "Show feature count".

Comment: Show features count works well for raster layers. I have a vector layer and there is no change for me

Comment: Show feature count will not work on raster layers. Only vector.